# How to iterate through two grouped queries to display both in a single per-month table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2 app I have a "dashboard" view that summarizes records from several models. For two of these models — lets call them Action and Event — I want to show historical counts-per-month in a single table. In other words the output will look something like:

```
    Action    Event
Jan  2          4
Feb  7          1
Mar  5          2
```

I understand how to achieve this for a single query, but because the `tr` tags are added while looping through records in the query, I can't see how to combine both. Is there an easy way to achieve this, or should I be looking for a simpler alternative?

```
#controller
class DashboardController
  def dashboard
    @actions = Action.all.group_by { |a| a.date_created.beginning_of_month }
    @events = Event.all.group_by { |e| e.date_created.beginning_of_month }
  end
end


#view
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
    <th>Events</th>
  </tr>
  #this correctly summarizes actions by month
  #how do I add events to this table?
  <% @actions.sort.each do |month, actions| %>
    <tr>
      <th><%= month.strftime('%B') %></th>
      <td><%= actions.count %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a wrapper for your data that will give you an array like

```
@data = []

(@actions.keys + @events.keys).uniq.sort.each { |month|
  data << { month: month, action: @actions[month].try(:length) || 0, event: @events[month].try(:length) || 0 }
}
```

will give you an arry of hashes like
`[ { month: 'Jan', actions: 2, events: 4}, { month: 'Feb', actions: 12, events: 14}]`

On which you can iterate easily.

or you could iterate through (@actions.keys + @events.keys) and then have

```
 <th><%= key.strftime('%B') %></th>
 <td><%= @actions[key].count %></td>
 <td><%= @events[key].count %></td>
```

Comment: thanks @xlembouras, could you explain this a little more please `You can use a wrapper for your data that will give you an array`. How do I create a wrapper?

Comment: thanks @xlembouras, this is almost exactly what I need. Though I'm being slow as the wrapper is not returning counts of actions/ events for each month, but is return an array of these objects. How do I get the count/size/length?

Comment: use `.try(:length)`, see above.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `zip` method to combine both arrays:

```
<% @actions.sort.zip(@events.sort).each do |action_group, event_group| %>
<tr>
  <th><%= action_group.first.strftime('%B') %></th>
  <td><%= action_group.last.count %></td>
  <td><%= event_group.last.count %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Docs are here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-zip

The caveat here is that both actions and events must be present for every month, otherwise the two arrays will have a different number of elements.

Comment: thanks Sudhir. This is a good solution, but as its conceivable in my particular case that actions or events may not be present for some months I've gone with xlemboruas answer